# Do contract calls atomically modify contract contents?

Tags: contract-development, database

Suppose a contract has the following:

```
uint[] arr;

function func(int a, int b) {
    arr.push(a);
    arr.push(b);
}
```

If two clients call *func* at essentially the same time with (1, 2) and (3, 4), are the contents of *arr* guaranteed to be in the order of the calls?

You would expect the order of modifications to be something like:

```
// contract.func(1, 2) call #1
arr.push(1); // #1
arr.push(2); // #1
// contract.func(3, 4) call #2
arr.push(3); // #2
arr.push(4); // #2
// arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, is it possible that the execution of events are interleaved as such:

```
// contract.func(1, 2) call #1
// contract.func(3, 4) call #2
arr.push(1); // #1
arr.push(2); // #2
arr.push(4); // #2
arr.push(3); // #1
// arr = [1, 2, 4, 3]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, contract calls are atomic and transactions run strictly in series, so you don't need to worry about different transactions treading on each other.

However, you don't know what order *transactions* will be processed in, so if #1 and #2 are different transactions (not just different calls within the same transaction) you could end up with transaction #2 being mined before transaction #1, resulting in:

```
// arr = [3, 4, 1, 2]
```